# Network link becomes dead when using bridge interface in Debian

Tags: networking, debian, linux-kvm, bridging

I have a hypervisor (Kernel-based Virtual Machine) running Debian buster which I recently upgraded from Debian stretch. I use network bridging to share my internet connection (it has two Ethernet ports) between all the VMs that run on the hypervisor. This has been working flawlessly for years until I upgraded to Debian buster a few months back. At first everything seems to work fine, but I found out that the hypervisor itself has no internet connection after adding the network bridge. While this happens, the VMs themselves do have a working internet connection, so it's working partially.

This is my configuration:

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.11
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.13 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.13 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
```

Where `192.168.1.13` is my own DNS server.

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/br0`

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.130
  bridge_ports eno1 eno2
  bridge_stp on
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_fd 0
```

And this is the only file there:

```
$ ls -la /etc/network/interfaces.d/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 13 03:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 13 03:13 ..
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  124 Nov  5 03:39 br0
```

When I disable the bridge by removing the `source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*` line, internet works just fine:

```
$ nc -vz www.google.nl 80
Connection to www.google.nl 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

When the bridge is enabled, internet stops working on the hypervisor (but the VMs do have internet):

```
$ nc -vz www.google.nl 80
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.google.nl != ams15s40-in-f3.1e100.net
www.google.nl [172.217.168.227] 80 (http) : No route to host

$ ssh 192.168.1.13 nc -vz www.google.nl 80
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: www.google.nl != ams15s40-in-f3.1e100.net
www.google.nl [172.217.168.227] 80 (http) open

$ traceroute -n www.google.nl
traceroute to www.google.nl (172.217.168.227), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.11  3075.828 ms !H  3075.817 ms !H  3075.814 ms !H

$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 onlink 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.130 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.11 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.12

$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:51:06:d8:89:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.11/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:51:06:d8:89:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.12/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:51:06:d8:89:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.130/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6651:6ff:fed8:89bc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:8d:65:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe8d:6533/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:46:f1:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe46:f15a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

I've tried several things. For example, I moved the `br0` stanza to `/etc/network/interfaces` and disabled the `source` line, but then I can't even SSH into the machine (why?). I've also tried different combinations of `dhcp` versus `static`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I've also tried removing the stanzas for `eno1` and `eno2` so that they simply get their address via DHCP, but same result. I've read the instructions on https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections but I'm completely stuck. It's extra frustrating since I know that this configuration used to work just fine. I hope anyone can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces that are bridge members no longer speak IP – only the bridge does. This means that any IP addresses on eno1 or eno2 are ignored and your default route with `dev eno1` becomes invalid as well.

So don't specify any address, netmask, broadcast, nor gateway on your physical interfaces – move all that configuration to br0:

```
iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.130/24
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    bridge_ports eno1 eno2
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

---

(In fact, do not configure 'broadcast' *at all*. The OS calculates it automatically from your netmask, so you're only specifying the value that has already been the default for ~40 years; it's just one more place to make a typo.)

Comment: Thank you! This fixes all of the above issues. Could you elaborate more on "bridge members no longer speak IP" or maybe point me to some documentation? Is this something that was changed recently?

Comment: It's been that way for as long as I can remember.